# Raw string to list of tuples

Tags: scala

I have below raw string and I want to convert it to List or List of tuples or List of maps, basically I need to iterate through foreach

```
val rawStr = "(foo,bar), (foo1,bar1), (foo3,bar3)"
```

How would I go for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string using any of `( , )` and then group

```
rawStr.split(s"""[(|,|)]""").filterNot(s => s.isEmpty || s.trim.isEmpty)
.grouped(2)
.toList
.map(pair => (pair(0), pair(1))).toList
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val rawStr = "(foo,bar), (foo1,bar1), (foo3,bar3)"
rawStr: String = "(foo,bar), (foo1,bar1), (foo3,bar3)"

scala> rawStr.split(s"""[(|,|)]""").filterNot(s => s.isEmpty || s.trim.isEmpty).grouped(2).toList.map(pair => (pair(0), pair(1))).toList
res13: List[(String, String)] = List(("foo", "bar"), ("foo1", "bar1"), ("foo3", "bar3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one can also deal with invalid input:

```
"\\(([^,]+{1})\\s*,\\s*([^,]+{1})\\)".r
  .findAllMatchIn(rawStr)
  .map(m => m.group(1) -> m.group(2)).toMap
```

You can give it

```
val rawStr = "(foo,bar,baz), (foo1,bar1), (foo3,bar3)"
```

or

```
val rawStr = "(foo), (foo1,bar1), (foo3,bar3)"
```

and it won't crash